# unbearably high ping only ingame on this specific server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Situation:
recently setup a modded minecraft server for me and my friends to play on were renting one of shockbyte, for the first few minutes the server was fine but then my ping randomly shot up to 1500 and the game stops updating til i recconnect then its fine for another couple minutes before it does the same thing.

Things ive tried:
*pinging the ip from cmd consistently gets 150ms same in the Minecraft server browser before i connect
*restarting my pc and factory resetting my internet
*changed the server location
*connecting through a vpn
*my friends from the same city can connect fine

My question:
is there anything else i can do to try diagnose my problem?

Comment: this seems like a server side issue

Comment: report to the hosting website, it may help.